# Android Java/PHP Uploading Image 404

Tags: java, php, android, post, image-uploading

I am currently trying to implement a profile image system, however, it does not seem to work at all. I am pretty sure that the problem is the php script that I am using. I want to emphasize that all my other php scripts are working, so the scripts for adding a user, fetching user details and even the one for fetching the profile image. I have no idea what it could be, so I am including the app source code as well. If I try to send a post to the php file, I always get a 404, not just in the app, hence it has to be the php scripts but I have no idea what could be the issue here. The writing process of the upload works but using the InputStreamReader just will not work. I really hope someone can help me, none of the solutions proposed in regards to this matter seem to cut it for me.

Calling the Async Task:

```
Uri filePath = data.getData();
Log.d("debugshit", "in if statement pic change");
try {
    final Bitmap profilePic = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
    ServerRequest sr = new ServerRequest(this, "Updating Profile...");
    sr.updateProfilePic(activeUser, profilePic, new ServerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(User returnedUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void done(boolean success) {
            if (success) {
                ((ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.navProfileImage)).setImageBitmap(profilePic);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Profile Picture updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Server Request class:

```
public void updateProfilePic(User user, Bitmap profilePic, ServerCallback callback) {
        progressDialog.show();
        new UpdateProfilePicTask(user, profilePic, callback).execute();
    }

    public class UpdateProfilePicTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        User user;
        Bitmap profilePic;
        ServerCallback callback;

        public UpdateProfilePicTask(User user, Bitmap profilePic, ServerCallback callback) {
            this.user = user;
            this.profilePic = profilePic;
            this.callback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://server/set_profilepic.php");
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setDoOutput(true);
                con.setDoInput(true);

                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8");

                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put("id", user.getId());
                contentValues.put("img_name", user.getUsername() + "_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".png");
                contentValues.put("encoded_img", encodeImage(profilePic));

                Log.d("debugshit", encodeParams(contentValues));

                con.connect();
                osw.write(encodeParams(contentValues));
                osw.flush();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String response = br.readLine();
                Log.d("debugshit", response);

                br.close();
                osw.close();
                os.close();
                con.disconnect();

                return response.equals("OK");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            callback.done(success);

            super.onPostExecute(success);
        }
    }

private String encodeImage(Bitmap image) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
        byte[] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    private String encodeParams(ContentValues values) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet = values.valueSet();
        boolean first = true;

        for(Map.Entry entry : entrySet) {
            String key = entry.getKey().toString();
            String value = entry.getValue().toString();

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                sb.append("&");

            sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            sb.append("=");
            sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

set_profilepic.php

```
<?php      

    header('Content-type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $imgname = $_POST['img_name'];
    $img = $_POST['encoded_img'];

    if (isset($imgname, $img)) {
        $decodedimg = base64_decode($img);
        $path = 'profile_images/' . $imgname;    

        $file = fopen($path, 'wb');
        $written = fwrite($file, $decodedimg);
        fclose($file);

        if ($written > 0) {
            $con = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "pw", "db");

            $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE User SET profilepic = ? WHERE id = ? ");

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "si", $path, $id);
            $success = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

            mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
            mysqli_close($con);

            if ($success) {
                echo "OK";
            }
            else {
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Error";
    }

?>
```

Comment: where is your server present. On your machine or on remote location?

Comment: `I always get a 404, not just in the app, hence it has to be the php scripts`. Wrong conclusion. Now what does 404 mean?

Comment: @greenapps I know what 404 means but when I go to the page, this error does not occur and the script is executed.

Comment: @Rohit Sharma it's on a remote location.

Comment: Now what does it mean then? And what do you mean with 'when i go to the page'? You have two methods or what? One wichs errors and the other not?

Comment: @greenapps it means the page is not found. If I use the web browser to navigate to the page, the scripts works and I can access it. The error only occurs when I use a post method.

Comment: Indeed the page is not found. Now who was looking for that page and did not find it and sent that 404?

Comment: The server returns the 404 error and the client tries to access the given page. As much as I enjoy this guessing game, I would prefer a direct answer. The page does exist and the name is spelled correctly, the 404 error occurs at some point when the script is executed. If I access the page and don't send any parameters, the code is executed proving that the page exists.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I managed to fix my error. The issue was that I had to change my permissions in order to get this to work. The writing permission was disabled by default, therefore I could not upload the file and it threw the 404 error.